# WP7 background blur effect

Tags: windows-phone-7, blur

I need to know, which is the best way to blur the background of the Windows Phone 7 app to concentrate the user's attention on a "always on top" popup window.

[image: WP7 Blured]

My idea is:

1. Make an in-memory screenshot of the background grid (by turning it into a freezable or something).
2. Add an image that overlaps the background grid, but is below (with the z-index) the popup.

Still I doubt I will be able to overlap the application bar.

At this point, if you have a solution, please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few pointers for you ...

Unfortunately the Silverlight BlurEffect and other Bitmap effects [didn't make it into Window Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/6cc6b56d-1fe9-4a70-b4b8-77fc99fc3ada), so you will have to implement the blur yourself. This is actually pretty simple, just use a [Gaussian Convolution Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur).

To achieve this effect you can capture the visuals of your application into a WriteableBitmap, manipulate the image to create your blur, then overlay this image over your application using a PopUp. I did something similar in a blog post I wrote about fly-out text animations here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/metro-in-motion-3-flying-titles/

Find your root visual as follows:

```
var rootElement = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
```

Add a copy of this UI into a popup as follows:

```
  _backgroundMask = new Rectangle()
  {
    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    Opacity = 0.0,
    Width = rootElement.ActualWidth,
    Height = rootElement.ActualHeight
  };
  _popupCanvas.Children.Add(_backgroundMask);

  _targetElementClone = new Image()
  {
    Source = new WriteableBitmap(element, null)
  };
  _popupCanvas.Children.Add(_targetElementClone);
```

And show it:

```
_popup.IsOpen = true;
```

I'll leave you to work out how to blur the background!

As an aside, your will not be able to overlay or capture the application bar visuals. Hide it before performing this transformation.

Finally, blurring the background isn't really very 'Metro'. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: No I am not. What would you advise as a mean of focusing the user on a popup? Given that I have a basic "black background" application, leaving everything as is on the background looks worse than blurring.

Comment: A simple opacity mask would do in my opinion. Use the code I have given above, but simply fill the popup with a black Rectangle with an Opacity="0.5"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blurring just use a semi transparent layer over the top of the page.

You should hide the application bar before trying to create such an effect as you won't be able to place anything on top of it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add a semi transparent layer? Which control do I span over my window?

Comment: @Maxim Adding a `Rectangle` and setting the `Opacity` should do it.